# Removing all overlays with duplicate values

Tags: overlays

My goal is to delete all duplicate overlay values from a list, and then remove every overlay in the buffer with values equal to each remaining element in the list.

I am having trouble understanding why `remove-overlays` does not remove every overlay in the buffer containing a specific value.  What appears to be happening is that `remove-overlays` removes **just the first** overlay it finds matching that specific value, and then it moves on to the next task without deleting the remainder of overlays with that same value.

I would like to delete duplicate values from the list using `(delq nil (delete-dups ov-list))`.

**EXAMPLE**

A test buffer contains the following text on the first line in the buffer:

```
############################
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
(let* (ov-value ov-list overlay limit char-at-point)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (setq limit (point-at-eol))
    (while (re-search-forward "#" limit t)
      (setq character (char-after (point)))
      (setq overlay (make-overlay (point) (1+ (point))))
      (setq ov-value (concat
          (propertize (char-to-string ?\uFEFF) 'face '(:background "yellow"))
          (propertize (char-to-string character) 'face '(:foreground "green"))))
      (push ov-value ov-list)
      (overlay-put overlay 'display ov-value)))
  (sit-for 2)
  (delq nil (delete-dups ov-list))
  (dolist (ov ov-list)
    (remove-overlays nil nil 'display ov)))
```

Comment: Try to find a different approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve.  You are building a quadratic time algorithm, which is bound to scale poorly to large buffers with many overlays.  At best, avoid duplicate overlays in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `remove-overlays` uses `eq` when testing an overlay-property's value.  But two strings are only `eq`ual, if they are the same object.

Usually one adds a symbol property with a constant value, usually `t`, in order to keep track of one's overlays.

Comment: `eq` implies `equal`.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is an example of how to remove duplicate overlay objects from a LIST when the text properties are the same:

```
(require 'cl)

(setq LIST
  (remove-duplicates LIST
    :test (lambda (x y) (or (null y) (equal-including-properties x y)))
    :from-end t))
```

The following function is an example of how to remove overlays when the value includes text properties.

```
(defun lawlist-remove-overlays (beg end name val)
"Remove the overlays that are `equal-including-properties`.
Includes a unique situation when an overlay with an `'after-string` property
is at the very end of a narrowed-buffer."
  (let* (
      (point-max (point-max))
      (point-min (point-min))
      (narrowed-p (buffer-narrowed-p))
      (beg (if beg beg point-min))
      (end
        (cond
          ((and
              (not narrowed-p)
              end)
            end)
          ((and
              (not narrowed-p)
              (null end))
            point-max)
          ((and
              narrowed-p
              end
              (< end point-max))
            end)
          ((and
              narrowed-p
              end
              (= end point-max))
            (1+ end))
          ((and
              narrowed-p
              (null end))
            (1+ point-max)) )) )
    (when (and beg end name val)
      (overlay-recenter end)
      (dolist (o (overlays-in beg end))
        (when (equal-including-properties (overlay-get o name) val)
          (delete-overlay o))))))
```

- Related threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817075/2112489

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/9836/2287