# Understanding why two apparently different overlay strings are `equal`

Tags: overlays

I am having trouble understanding why two apparently different overlay strings are `equal`.  The following test results positive -- i.e., `t`.  The colors are different and the `:data` identification names are different -- i.e., the first name is `pilcrow_plain_xpm`; whereas the second name is `pilcrow_active_region_xpm`.

**Q**:  Why are they `equal`?

```
(equal

  #(" " 0 1
    (display
      (image :type xpm :mask nil :ascent center :data
        "/* XPM */
        static char * pilcrow_plain_xpm[] = {
        \"11 20 4 1\",
        \". c #000000\",
        \"+ c #555555\",
        \"@ c #7F0000\",
        \"% c yellow\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...++++++..\",
        \"..++++.+...\",
        \"..++++.+...\",
        \"..++++.+...\",
        \"...+++.+...\",
        \".....+.+...\",
        \".....+.+...\",
        \".....+.+...\",
        \".....+.+...\",
        \".....+.+...\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\",
        \"...........\"};")
           cursor t))

  #(" " 0 1
    (display
      (image :type xpm :mask nil :ascent center :data
       "/* XPM */
       static char * pilcrow_active_region_xpm[] = {
       \"11 20 4 1\",
       \". c #3c3c3c\",
       \"+ c #555555\",
       \"@ c #7F0000\",
       \"% c yellow\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..++++++..\",
       \"%.++++.+...\",
       \"%.++++.+...\",
       \"%.++++.+...\",
       \"%..+++.+...\",
       \"%....+.+...\",
       \"%....+.+...\",
       \"%....+.+...\",
       \"%....+.+...\",
       \"%....+.+...\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\",
       \"%..........\"};")
          cursor t)) )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`equal` compares by string content and ignores text properties.  If you wish to include properties into your check, use `equal-including-properties`.